# Eclipse IDE crashes in EndeavourOS

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run Eclipse IDE in EndeavourOS and it crashes while trying to open the marketplace. I've already tried to use the installer and the portable version, with the same result. Here is the [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RIYi.png): I'm just posting
the beginning since it's very long.

Comment: Are you sure Eclipse works with Java 22?  I would encourage an LTS release like Java 21 or 17.  Non-LTS releases tend to be a bit flaky and not always well supported across tools.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. Just tried Java 21 to be sure, the problem is occurring just as before.

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed it! I was running Eclipse on Wayland, so I switched back to X11 by exporting an environment variable for the IDE:

> export GDK_BACKEND=x11

Now it's working